# How to get abbreviated month name as X-axis in Linechart in DC.js

Tags: d3.js, axis, dc.js, linechart

I am trying to get abbreviated month name in X-axis for DC.js line chart. I have formatted the month column and parsed it before sending it to dimension.Even after formatting the ticks in the line chart, I am getting "Dec" for all of them. Below is the code . Please help me to resolve it

```
 var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%B %d, %Y");
    var parseMonth = d3.timeFormat("%B");

    canadaclimatProjects.forEach(function (d) {

        var date = parseTime(d["year_mon"]);
        d["year_mon"] = parseMonth(date);
    });

var newMonth = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d["year_mon"]; });

monthlyPrecipitationChart
        .width(380)
        .height(250)
        .round(d3.timeMonth.round)
        .xUnits(d3.timeMonths)
        .x(d3.scaleTime().domain(newMonth))
        .dimension(newMonth)
        .group(precipitationByMonth)
        .brushOn(false)
        .valueAccessor(function (p) { return p.value.count > 0 ?      p.value.total / p.value.count : 0; })
        .elasticX(true)
        .elasticY(true);
        .xAxis().ticks(12).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`d3.scaleTime()` won't work if you are passing in strings as the keys of your data. You need to pass in Date objects instead.

You've already handled printing the ticks with abbreviated months with

```
    .xAxis().ticks(12).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b"));
```

so it's redundant (and won't work) to format the dates on input.

Rarely is it a good idea to pass formatted data into a chart. Formatting usually happens after the chart is drawn.

Hard to say why you are getting the results you describe, without a complete runnable example.